# setup:db:status still reports "Declarative Schema is not up to date" after update

Tags: magento2.3, setup-upgrade, magento2.3.2, declarative-schema

Since an update to Magento 2.3 I am experiencing the following issue:

```
bin/magento setup:db:status
Declarative Schema is not up to date
Run setup:upgrade to update your DB schema and data.
```

Although `setup:upgrade` has already been executed.

I've inspected the diff  from `\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\UpToDateDeclarativeSchema::isUpToDate()` and see the following elements reported as not up to date:

```
id  type    old_type    new_type    new_name
0   drop_reference  reference   reference   MAGENTO_TARGETRULE_PRD_PRD_ID_SEQUENCE_PRD_SEQUENCE_VAL
0   drop_reference  reference   reference   MAGENTO_CATEVENT_EVENT_CTGR_ID_SEQUENCE_CAT_CTGR_SEQUENCE_VAL
0   drop_reference  reference   reference   FK_12C2962523CC7EF2EA73AD4121B5DBFF
0   drop_reference  reference   reference   MAGENTO_BANNER_CATRULE_RULE_ID_SEQUENCE_CATRULE_SEQUENCE_VAL
0   drop_reference  reference   reference   MAGENTO_BANNER_SALESRULE_RULE_ID_SEQUENCE_SALESRULE_SEQUENCE_VAL
0   drop_reference  reference   reference   FK_81ACD87B0CB5AB8CC9B8D0B05F30FBB8
0   drop_reference  reference   reference   MAGENTO_SALESRULE_FILTER_RULE_ID_SEQUENCE_SALESRULE_SEQUENCE_VAL
0   drop_reference  reference   reference   MAGENTO_CATPERMISSIONS_CTGR_ID_SEQUENCE_CAT_CTGR_SEQUENCE_VAL
0   drop_reference  reference   reference   VISUAL_MERCHANDISER_RULE_CTGR_ID_SEQUENCE_CAT_CTGR_SEQUENCE_VAL
249 add_complex_element NONE    reference   MAGENTO_TARGETRULE_PRD_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID
303 add_complex_element NONE    reference   MAGENTO_CATEVENT_EVENT_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID
326 add_complex_element NONE    reference   MAGENTO_VERSIONSCMS_HIERARCHY_NODE_PAGE_ID_CMS_PAGE_PAGE_ID
331 add_complex_element NONE    reference   MAGENTO_BANNER_CATALOGRULE_RULE_ID_CATALOGRULE_RULE_ID
332 add_complex_element NONE    reference   MAGENTO_BANNER_SALESRULE_RULE_ID_SALESRULE_RULE_ID
346 add_complex_element NONE    reference   MAGENTO_REMINDER_RULE_SALESRULE_ID_SALESRULE_RULE_ID
381 add_complex_element NONE    reference   MAGENTO_SALESRULE_FILTER_RULE_ID_SALESRULE_RULE_ID
383 modify_column   decimal decimal adjustment_positive
383 modify_column   decimal decimal adjustment_negative
388 add_complex_element NONE    reference   MAGENTO_CATPERMISSIONS_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID
396 add_complex_element NONE    reference   VISUAL_MERCHANDISER_RULE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID
```

Any idea, why indexes etc. are not updated? If I look at the `magento_targetrule_product` table for example, the constraint that should have been dropped is indeed still there and the new one has not been added.

Comment: Found a related Github issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19597

Answer (score 0):

Firstly generate a whitelist JSON for your module.

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=[MODULE-NAME]
```

After whitelist file generation run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Now check the status using below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:db:status
```